# viewing database using php in different way

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am doing simple shopping site and I only know how to view the products from the database in table such as this code below.

```
<table  width ="793" align ="center" border ="5" >     

<tr bgcolor ="red">
<th width="90">product No </th>    
<th>User Name  </th>   
<th width="184">product name</th>   
<th>product price</th>  
<th>Edit product</th> 
<th>Delete product</th> 
</tr>    

<?php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","root");
mysql_select_db("db");
$query = "SELECT * FROM products";
$run = mysql_query($query);

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($run))
{

echo "<tr>";
echo '<td align="center"><font color="white"><b>' . $row['id'] . '</b></td>';
echo '<td align="center"><font color="white"><b>' . $row['product_name'] . '</b></td>';
echo '<td align="center"><font color="white"><b>' . $row['product_price'] . '</b></td>';
echo '<td align="center"><a href="edit.php?id=' . $row['id'] . '"><font color=" #e52d00">   <b>Edit</b></a></td>';
echo '<td align="center"><a href="delete.php?id=' . $row['id'].'"><font color=" #e52d00"><b>Delete</b></a></td>';
echo "</tr>"; 
} 
echo "</table>";

?>

</body>
</html>
```

and I want to know how to view data in way such as amazon or ebay. I mean inside table.

I hope you know what I mean.

Comment: If you want to make a similar design to Amazon and other shopping websites, you should read some CSS guides. You'll get the required tools for this task. Good luck.

Comment: You most likely will be using divs and CSS styling, not tables

Comment: I made it but how can I make the result seperated from each othe?

Comment: I need an example of similar css code

Answer (score 1):

Please use CSS to format the resultset..